# Pagination linking to all black page

Tags: pagination

I've set up what I thought to be simple pagination links but when you click a link, it goes to an all blank/black page. Anyone ever experienced this?
Here is my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="4" dynamic="yes" paginate="bottom"}
    <div class="entry">
    <img src="{news_image}" alt=""/>
      <h2 class="h1-grey">{title}</h2>
      <span class="date">{news_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</span>
      <span class="source">{news_source}</span>
      <p>{news_summary}</p>
      <span class="readmore-news"><a href="news/article/{url_title}">READ MORE &#62;</a></span>
    </div>
    {paginate}
      {pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to to get my paginations working by simply adding an extra segment to my url for my news articles. Before the url was site.com/news. For some unknown reason, my pagination would not work from this page. It would simply link to an all black page. When I change my URL to site.com/news/articles, it works fine. Would still appreciate any kind of explanation from someone when time permits. Thanks.